# Is there any tool to creating big size OpenStreetMap JPEG map

Tags: gis, openstreetmap, arcgis, qgis, cartography

I got request to create several OpenStreetMap JPEG map with various size (from 1.5km x 1.5km, 12km x 12km, and 96km x 96km) in country level.

I wondering is there any tool or software to be able to create the map with size like that (from 1.5km x 1.5km until 96km x 96).

I already tested with QGIS map composer but it seems they only allow to create until 100.000 mm.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles) you are interested in (be sure to read and follow the [tile usage policy](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy)!). Which tiles to fetch can be calculated, take a look at the [slippy map tilenames](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames) page. Then just stitch your JPEGs together to a large image, for example by using imagemagick.

Alternatively you can use [bigmap / bigmap2](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Bigmap) which does something very similar.

Answer (score -1):

I wonder if something like [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) would work as it could automatically align the tiles.

Answer (score -1):

I have successfully rendered large maps for printing posters using [nik2img](https://github.com/springmeyer/nik2img).

The process is roughly the following:

1. Import data for the area you need to render from OpenStreetMap to a local PostgreSQL server. You can get area extracts from [various sources](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Downloading).
2. Render the data from local database to image with `nik2img`.